# What is the purpose of having timezone.offset value in Calendar Instance when created with IST Timezone?

Tags: java, android, datetime, kotlin, calendar

Created **Calendar.getInstance()** and tried of using **instance.timezone.offset** value, which is wrong value when compared with UTC time.

Eg:

**UTC+5:30 --  GMT+5:30 -- Add 5 Hrs (5*1000*60*60) + 30 mins (1000*60*30) to UTC time**

**UTC-3:00 -- GMT-3:00 -- Subtract 3 Hrs (3*1000*60*60) to UTC time**

In both cases, Offset value from the Calendar Instance is not proper value as above calculated values.

Kindly Share details purpose of usage of Offset values from Calendar Instance.

```
Calendar modelDaysST = Calendar.getInstance();
Long offsetValue = modelDaysST.getTimeZone().getRawOffset();
modelDaysST.add(Calendar.DATE, noOfDays)
modelDaysST.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
modelDaysST.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
modelDaysST.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
modelDaysST.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
Calendar scheduleStartTime = null
workScheduleModel.workingScheduleStartTime?.let {
scheduleStartTime=DateUtils.getCalendarFromTime(it,DateUtils.DATE_FORMAT_HH_mm_ss)}
modelDaysST.timeInMillis += ((scheduleStartTime?.timeInMillis ?: 0) + offsetValue)
```

Comment: Show code that causes the problem.

Comment: Edited my code.Kindly check

Comment: What will `modelDaysST.getTimeZone()` and `TimeZone.getDefault()` print

Comment: When on Java 8, use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html

Comment: @s1m0nw1, I was asking the purpose of the timezone.getRawOffset() method usage. Not the alternative usage. Kindly explain.

Comment: The method is used internally in some subclasses of `Calendar`. I am not aware of any use for it for ordinary application programmers, and not convinced that there is one. Leaving aside the fact that `TimeZone` and `Calendar` are old and have been supplanted five years ago by `ZoneId` and `ZonedDateTime` (roughly).

Comment: [I cannot reproduce your issue.](https://ideone.com/72aqtq) For IST I get a raw offset of 19 800 000 milliseconds, which agrees with your 5*1000*60*60 + 1000*60*30 = 18 000 000 + 1 800 000 = 19 800 000. What do you get instead? Could you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about an issue that cannot be reproduced, and answers about the intended use of `getRawOffset` would have to be guesswork, that is, not really 
useful.